# Codeigniter Rest server Digest or Basic auth cant login

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I'm using Phil Sturgeon’s REST Server. I'm having trouble to set up the basic or digest authentication. When calling the method i get the dialog that prompts for username and password even if i write in the correct username and password it wont accept it. How do i troubleshoot this ? Is it my web host that doesnt allow it ?

This is how i set up the auth in rest.php:
The rest is default.

```
$config['rest_auth']         = 'Basic';
$config['auth_source']       = '';
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = array('admin' => 'password');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I had to add this on my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for writing in such an old thread. Thought it may save somebody's time.

Please note that this solution is for basic auth only. I have not tested this with digest auth.

I required to tweak @Tan's answer a bit to get the .htaccess to work.

I removed the `[L]` from `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]` and placed the rewrite rule just after `RewriteEngine on`

The .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

#Other rules follow
```

Next, I required to change the rest.php config file inside application/config directory. The changes I made are as follows:

`$config['auth_source'] = 'ldap'` to `$config['auth_source'] = 'library'`,
`$config['auth_library_class'] = ''` to `$config['auth_library_class'] = 'api_auth'`
`$config['auth_library_function'] = ''` to `$config['auth_library_function'] = 'login'`

Then, I created a new library file named Api_auth.php having the following code:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Api_auth
{
    public function login($username, $password) {
        if($username == 'admin' && $password == '1234')
        {
            return true;            
        }
        else
        {
            return false;           
        }           
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone someday.

Comment: pls which of the rest server implementation are you using?

Answer (score 4):

this didnt work for me but this did

for me It related the the sever running php as a fastCGI, not a php5_module, like your localhost does. ( to find this out run phpinfo - Server API: CGI/FastCGI )

here was the solution
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/173823/#825912

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

libraries/REST_Controller.php

BEFORE

```
// most other servers
elseif ($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION'))
{
if (strpos(strtolower($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION')),'basic') === 0)
{
    list($username,$password) = explode(':',base64_decode(substr($this->input-  >server('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'), 6)));
}
}
```

AFTER

```
// most other servers
elseif ( $this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION') || $this->input-    >server('REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER') )
{
$HTTP_SERVER_AUTH = ($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION')) ? $this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION') : $this->input->server('REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER'); 

if (strpos(strtolower($HTTP_SERVER_AUTH),'basic') === 0)
{
    list($username,$password) = explode(':',base64_decode(substr($HTTP_SERVER_AUTH, 6)));
}
}
```

Comment: is your authentication digest or library